# Time zone in google app script, how to set it

Tags: datetime, google-apps-script, timezone

```
function dailyEventMessage() {
  var today = new Date(); 
  Logger.log(today);
}
```

When I write an easy code like this, why in new file it show

```
12:33:47 PM Notice  Execution started
12:33:47 PM Info    Thu Dec 24 00:33:47 GMT-05:00 2020
12:33:48 PM Notice  Execution completed
```

old file show

```
12:42:59 PM Notice  Execution started
12:42:59 PM Info    Thu Dec 24 12:42:59 GMT+07:00 2020
12:43:00 PM Notice  Execution completed
```

Even it is the same code? how can I default every new file to set time zone at GMT+7

Comment: I cannot understand about `new file` and `old file`. I apologize for this. Can I ask you about the detail of them?

Comment: Sorry, its new project in app script. Not a new file , sorry.

Comment: Thank you for replying. In that case, I thought that this issue might be related to your situation. https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/175718931 If it's so, how about checking the time zone at the manifest file (`appsscript.json`)? But I'm not sure whether this is the direct solution of your issue. I apologize for this.

Comment: Yes it is what you said is correct , however, I can't see appscript.json. They said to check in setting but unfortunately , I can't find mine.

Comment: Cloaing as duplicate. See linked answer to see how to unhide the manifest file

Comment: Yes, finally I found it, correct appsscipt.json. Thru file in new script editor screen. Or adding to it if not found.

Comment: Consider adding a answer to the duplicate question, if what you've found is significantly different from the other answers.